# Abstract rigorous Multivariable Calc textbook

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

I just finished a theoretical calc3 course, the main text for the course was Spivak's Manifolds. I supplemented with Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds. The course heavily focused on the geometry of things. I' looking for a textbook for self-study, considering either Calculus of Several Variables by Serge Lang or Functions of Several Variables by Wendell H. Fleming. What's the core difference between the two and what would be the better choice?

Edit: I'm an applied mathematics student doing a lot of machine learning related courses (also what I want to do in the future). I think it's very important to understand the theoretical base behind the computational stuff (also generally love math), which is what I'm looking to learn either from Lang or Fleming.
The course that I did was designated for pure math majors and was very heavily differential geometry centered, which was interesting, but it kind of grazed over the other stuff assuming that the math majors will be leaning that in real analysis

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recommend checking out Hubbard and Hubbard and also Shifrin’s book Multivariable Mathematics.

Comment: If you have some analysis background, Chapter 9 of Rudin's PMA should be a good start to learn about the big Theorems.  (Rank, Inverse, Implicit Theorem). Look into advanced linear algebra books as well, preferably one with tensors.

Comment: Rudin Chapter 9 is without a doubt the worst place to learn multivariable analysis. The OP has already studied Munkres and Spivak. I haven't looked at Lang's book in years, but as I recall it's mostly a computational calculus text. Fleming is on a par with Munkres (and more readable than Spivak), except that he includes Lebesgue integration for all the multivariable integration material.